# glb/gltf file shows pixelated texture

Tags: rendering, export, gltf, three.js

I have exported a glb/gltf file from Blender for a model. But when I view the file in a gltf viewer it shows a pixelated texture.

I am not able to figure out the issue. Is it the inherent model issue? Or the texture file issue? Also, my glb file export file is around 10 MB.

Can you please help me with some leads? I am attaching a picture of the same. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What Blender version?

Comment: I am using 2.91.2 version

Comment: It's a bug in 2.91: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/1285. Update to 2.92.